# Filter based on nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have the following Array structure:

```
[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

One of the object inside this array can look like this:

```
[
    {
        name: 'testing', 
        other: 'value',
        ratings: [{category : 'passives'} , {category : 'detractor'}]
    }, 
    {
        name: 'testing2', 
        other: 'value',
        ratings: [{category : 'detractor'}]
    }
]
```

I want to select all the objects inside the array that includes a rating with the category passive.

So with the above object the return value should look like:

```
[
    {
        name: 'testing', 
        other: 'value',
        ratings: [{category : 'passives'} , {category : 'detractor'}]
    }
]
```

The reason is because that's the only object in the array that has a ratings with the category of passive included.

I tried something like:

```
 const response = 'passives'
 const ape = object.filter(project => {
     return project.ratings.filter(item => {
         return item.category === response
     })
 })
```

Comment: Change the inner `filter` to [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Comment: And what going wrong? Except you try compare `'passive'` with `'passives'`

Comment: @Darth sorry typo, not in my code tho. In this question

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I'll give it a try

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov that should be contained in your answer, not in a comment that might potentially get deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if your inner `.filter()` returns an empty array it is evaluated as truthy by outer `.filter()`, so it won't actually filter anything.

If you need to return boolean (`true` or `false`), based on whether nested array includes object having desired property value,  [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is a perfect choice

```js
const src = [{name:'testing',other:'value',ratings:[{category:'passives'},{category:'detractor'}]},{name:'testing2',other:'value',ratings:[{category:'detractor'}]}],
    
      result = src.filter(({ratings}) => 
                ratings.some(({category}) => 
                  category == 'passives'))
    
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: this is perfect thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: "testing",
    other: "value",
    ratings: [{ category: "passives" }, { category: "detractor" }],
  },

  {
    name: "testing2",
    other: "value",
    ratings: [{ category: "detractor" }],
  },
]

const res = arr.filter((obj) =>
  obj.ratings.find((rating) => rating.category === "passives") !== undefined
)

console.log(res)
```

Comment: `find` is not idiomatic here, and only coincidentally works in this case. As a counter example, if each object had an array of booleans and you were searching for a value of `false`, this would not work. **edit** I see you added the `!== undefined` but my underlying point still stands, it's not idiomatic code.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I have compared with `undefined`. Moreover, no his case not involving any `false` values, so consider counter examples here is some kind of over-engineering.

Comment: Using `some()` instead of `find() !== undefined` is not "over-engineering", it's plain-and-simple idiomatic, _correct_ code.

Comment: what is considered *incorrect* here, even in his question he cited *includes a rating with the category*, so just have to make sure to have one is enough. Moreover, the object shape has nothing to deal with boolean value, so why bothers counter example here?

Comment: There's more to programming than just getting the code to work. If it doesn't correctly communicate the intent, it makes the code harder to maintain. I'll turn the question around and ask why you bother to choose less than the best available builtin method that's designed exactly for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example:

```js
let arr = [
    {
        name : 'testing', 
        other: 'value',
        ratings : [{category : 'passives'} , {category : 'detractor'}]
    }, 

    {
        name : 'testing2', 
        other: 'value',
        ratings : [{category : 'detractor'}]
    }
];

const response = 'passives'
const ape = [];

arr.map(project => {
    const filtered = project.ratings.filter(item => item.category === response);
    if(filtered.length > 0) {
        ape.push(project);
    }
});

console.log(ape);
```

Comment: This is a completely inappropriate use of `map`.

Comment: You'd be much better off with `Array.prototype.forEach()` for simple looping

Comment: Or just using the idiomatic `filter()`, as was already the case...